# JQUERY > Loading function from parent window is not working

Tags: jquery, function, load, window, parent

I´m having some trouble while trying to execute a function from a parent window.

In a quick search here at stackoverflow, i found some threads about this same issue, but none of them have a solution that works with me. And i really don´t know where is the problem.

Here is the test code i´m trying out:

---

(main page)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    function test(){
        alert("It Works");  
    }
    $('.loadpg').load('teste5b.php');   
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="loadpg" style="display:block;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

(loaded page)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.parent.$.test();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a>Click Here</a>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Basicaly, i need this because i´m coding a modal window plugin to use in my application, and i will use this modal window to load a short form to update my database. When the modal window closes, The parent window with be updated.

I need to load the parent window function to close the modal window and to update the content of the main page after the db update.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function **test** isn't reachable because it is inside of the document.ready function closure. Put it outside of it, and you'll be able to access it normally by:

```
// the parent page:
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.loadpg').load('teste5b.php');  
});

function test () { /* your function here */ }

// inside your loaded page, you can call it like this:
window.parent.test();
```

Comment: Thank you so much mcpDESIGNS. now it work just fine! I have tried once to put the function outside de ready, but in the loaded page i was trying to run the function like that: window.parent.$.test() ... The way you pointed me out work just fine! Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem, also the way you were calling it. `window.parent.$.test()` the **$** was as if you had a jQuery extension (not a normal window function) called test. A little different!

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I´m pretty new on coding, and these little details some times get us some real trouble... Would like to give you a vote up but i don´t have reputation for that =(

Comment: It´s +15 to be able to vote... will try to answere some questions to get reputation and do your deserved vote. Thanks again!